Error of the Runge-Kutta method
In my university excercise I've run into an ODE system
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d\rho}{dr} = - \frac{m}{r^2}, \\
\frac{dm}{dr} = \rho r^2, \\
\rho(0)=1, m(0) = 0.
\end{cases}$$
The analytical solution to this system is
$$\begin{cases}
\rho = \frac{\sin r}{r}, \\
m = \sin r - r \cos r.
\end{cases}$$
I'm asked to solve this system using the classic RK4 method and check if error = $O(h^4)$. But the actual error I've got is somewhere near $O(h^2)$. When I tried to put the solution for $m$ into the expression for $\frac{d\rho}{dr}$ that is basically turned the system into one ODE I actually got $O(h^4)$. So my question is what is special about this system and how error depends on given system in general.

might be because in the region $r = O(h)$, the system will suffer from some error like $\frac{\text{truncation error  in  m}}{r^2}$. When your $m$ is analytic, you do not suffer from that.

How did you treat the singularity at the initial point?

I used (0,0) for derivatives and (1,0) for analytical solution

I would try starting the integration at some finite value of $r$, say $r_0 = 10^{-3}$. You can estimate the IC there from a power-series expansion (possible to do without knowing the solution using the ODE) to get $\rho \simeq 1 - r_0^2/6$ and $m\simeq r_0^3/3$. The error in the IC is $O(r_0^4) = 10^{-12}$ here. This will likely improve the convergence. The further away from $r=0$ you get the more it should give the $O(h^4)$ behavior, which you need to balance against knowing the IC to to high enough accuracy.

One way to see what happens in your case is to compute take one single step away from $r=0$ using the method you use (putting $\rho'(0) = 0$). The solution you find (to $O(h^4)$) is $(\rho,m) = (1-5h^2/24, h^3/3)$ while the true solution to the same order should be $(\rho,m) = (1-h^2/6, h^3/3)$. Thus you have already gotten an error of $h^2/24$ in $\rho$ in the first step.

@Winther It actually works. Thank you! So is it because $\rho'$ has $r$ in the denominator even though it has a finite limit or something else? And what breaks in the proof of $O(h^4)$ error in this case?

Take a look at the standard proof that RK4 has global error $O(h^4)$. Is there any assumptions that might not hold? If they don't hold then you should not expect $O(h^4)$. Hint: we assume something about the RHS function of $(m,\rho)' = F(r,m,\rho)$ in this proof. For the actual solution we follow the path $F(r,r^3/3,1-r^2/6)$ close to $r=0$ which is well behaved even as $r\to 0$, but this is not true in general. For example away from $r=0$ we also have that $(\rho, m) = (\cos(r)/r, \sin(r)r - \cos(r))$ is a solution with $m(0) = -1$ and where the density $\rho$  blows up at the origin.

@Winther I think I understood the case we start exactly from $0$ but I still not sure what happens when we start from small but finite value like $10^{-3}$. In this case results are better but I could actually get $O(h^4)$ only if I start from like $0.1$.

You probably will need to be a bit removed from $r=0$, but how far is “enough” will likely depend on $h$ which complicates things further. You might also not get the $O(h^4)$ behaviour until $h$ is small enough and at that point there are also issues like truncation errors to worry about... I think the main takeaway from this example is that around a singular point you cannot generally expect to get the usual $O(h^4)$ convergence.

Since $f(r,\rho,m)=(-\frac{m}{r^2}, \rho r^2)$ is discontinuous at $r=0$, you can't use Runge-Kutta's method, though the system has the explicit solution.
